# En que iteración me encuentro en R con un for?

Tags: r, bucle-for, bucles

Estoy tratando de resolver un problema de implementación de una ANFIS y de las funciones de base radial (RBF, Radial Basis Function) en R.
El problema es que tarda mucho en realizar las funciones y quería poner un indicador de como  va.
usando la función print(i), pero esto dentro de un for(i in conjunto) pero esto no funciona ya que muestra el objeto i con el que se esta tratando.
Se que puedo obtener el tamaño del conjunto con length(conjunto) pero lo que necesito es el nº de i que esta realizando y no el objeto completo.
Alguien sabe como hacerlo,
**Nota: no tengo mucha idea de R.**
Lo que querría seria algo asi:

```
for(i in conjunto){
  iter = i.getNIteacion()
  print(paste(iter,"/",length(conjuto))
}
```

Comment: No sé lo que es `iter`, pero imagino que lo que buscas es más bien algo como esto: `print(paste(i,"/",length(conjunto)))`

Comment: Si,  seria correcto i fuera un integer y no un objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es iterar por un índice y no por los objetos:

```
n <- length(conjunto)
for(i in 1:n){
  iter = conjunto[[i]].getNIteacion()
  print(paste(i,"/",n)
}
```

Suponiendo que `conjunto` es alguna especie de lista, iteramos de 1 a `length(conjunto)`, en este caso `i` será un índice numérico y no un objeto, luego para acceder al objeto en sí usamos los corchetes dobles: `conjunto[[i]]`, y ahora sí podemos hacer: `print(paste(i,"/",n)`

Comment: Bien pensado pero el metodo getNIteacion() no existe en R, es algo para decir lo que pretendo. Además de que por como esta construido el for rn R, i siempre será un objeto.

Comment: Suponía que tu pregunta venía por el  lado de mostrar el número de iteracion cuando está iterando una lista de objetos, ¿mi respuesta resuelve tu pregunta? ¿o entendí otra cosa? saludos.